# How to test controller with auth via jwt

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jwt

I'm new in Spring. I need to know how to test my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/game")
class GameController {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var gameRepository: GameRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var gameService: GameService

    @PostMapping("/start")
    fun start(@CurrentUser currentUser: UserPrincipal): Game {
        val user = userRepository.findById(currentUser.id!!).get()
        return gameService.createGame(user)
    }
}
```

I use jwt token to auth, and I cannot test my controller without it now. How to do it? How to mock it?